# Jacod & Protter Probability Essentials: Mistake in exercise 12.6

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, covariance

I tried solving exercise 12.6 in the second edition of the book probability essentials by Jacod & Protter. The exercise is as follows

> $12.6$ Let $X, Y$ have finite variances and let
> $$
> Z=\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_{Y}}\right) Y-\left(\frac{\rho_{X, Y}}{\sigma_{X}}\right) X
> $$
> Show that $\sigma_{Z}^{2}=1-\rho_{X, Y}^{2}$, and deduce that if $\rho_{X, Y}=\pm 1$, then $Y$ is a non-constant affine function of $X$.

In my opinion the variance won't work out as $\sigma_{Z}^{2}=1-\rho_{X, Y}^{2}$ but instead will be $\sigma_{Z}^{2}=1-3\rho_{X, Y}^{2}$. I found a solution on the internet which in my opinion also shows that $\sigma_{Z}^{2}=1-3\rho_{X, Y}^{2}$ is the true value, but in this solution they also claim that $\sigma_{Z}^{2}=1-\rho_{X, Y}^{2}$. Here is the part of the solution which is wrong in my opinion.

> $$\text { Let } Z=\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_{Y}}\right) Y-\left(\frac{\rho_{X Y}}{\sigma_{X}}\right) X$$
> $$\Rightarrow \sigma_{Z}^{2}=\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}\right) \sigma_{Y}^{2}-\left(\frac{\rho_{X Y}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}^{2}}\right) \sigma_{X}^{2}-2\left(\frac{\rho_{X Y}}{\sigma_{X} \sigma_{Y}}\right) \operatorname{Cov}(X, Y).
> $$

But $\rho_{XY}$=$\dfrac{\text{Cov(X,Y)}}{\sigma{(X)}\sigma{(Y)}}$ and therefore
$$2\left(\frac{\rho_{X Y}}{\sigma_{X} \sigma_{Y}}\right) \operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = \rho_{XY}^2$$

Now, am I not getting something really basic or what's going on ?

Comment: As the answer below suggests, the covariance is a bilinear form and you have something like a binomial formula. So you can write $\sigma_Z^2=\mathrm{Cov}(Z,Z)$ and look what happens.

Comment: That's a nice approach as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you have a small mistake in how you compute the variance of $Z$. It should be:

$$ \sigma_{Z}^{2}=\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_{Y}^{2}}\right) \sigma_{Y}^{2}+\left(\frac{\rho_{X Y}^{2}}{\sigma_{X}^{2}}\right) \sigma_{X}^{2}-2\left(\frac{\rho_{X Y}}{\sigma_{X} \sigma_{Y}}\right) \operatorname{Cov}(X, Y).$$

Comment: I see, thanks. The fact that this solution had it wrong also got me really confused.